# string convert to array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want split a string to array by Case Sensitivity. like

```
$str = 'CreateTechBook'
```

convert to

```
 array('Create','Tech', 'Book')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function splitCamelCase($str) {
    return preg_split('/(?<=\\w)(?=[A-Z])/', $str);
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Btw `(?<=\\w)` imho can be improved to `(?<!^)`

Comment: @zerkms Yep, that will be nice~

Answer (score 0):

```
 preg_replace('/([a-z0-9])?([A-Z])/','$1 $2 $3',$string);
```